SQL Connection .Net Core and Lag
Regarding audit login logout
This is correct, but not complete.  It correctly identifies a useful SQL Profiler EventSubClass, that in theory identifies when pooling is working. In real life however not-so-much.
I'm migrating an app and I can see in a real-world scenario, side-by-side, the new connection string performance vs. the old connection string performance.  I'm calling the exact same stored procedures on the exact same DB.  In the new .NET Core 8 app there is what appears to be connection lag of 10-30 seconds with each call.  Every time the new app calls a proc there is an audit-login audit-logout.  The old string (Classic ASP) has zero lag and there is just one, the initial connection, audit-login-logout in SQL Profiler.  Both report in EventSubClass that pooling is working.
Classic ASP string
strConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=192.168.50.123,25123;Database=mydb_2;Uid=yyyyy;Pwd=xxxxx;pooling=true"

.NET Core 8 appsettings.json
"default": "Data Source=192.168.50.123,25123;Initial Catalog=mydb_2; uid=yyyyy;pwd=xxxxx;pooling=true"

Now, I realized that could be a coincidence, that is, there might be something, non-connection-string-related in the migrated .NET Core app, but I can't find anything.  I appear to be using .NET Core best practices when calling the SQL Server 2019 DB.
Update #!
I originally thought this was a pooling issue, but I found it was pooling fine.
Here's a typical SQL Command call, below.  Note that it's in a using block.

Here is the code of a typical service
using FFD.Core.DTOs;
using FFD.Core.Helper;
using FFD.Core.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace FFD.Core.Services
{
    public class RoboCheatService : IRoboCheatService
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        public RoboCheatService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // _userRepository = userRepository;
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("default");
        }
        public List<RoboCheatDTO> GetRoboCheatData(RoboCheatXmlDTO obj)
        {
            try
            {
                List<RoboCheatDTO> Test1 =new List<RoboCheatDTO>();
                int user_Number = obj.personId;
                bool bAll = false;
                bool bUpdate = false;
                bool bUpdateWithCheat = false;
                int uft = 0;
                int iRunIdCH = 0;
                int iRunbefore = 0;
                int iRunIdFC = 0;
                bool bUpdateNpoWithCheat = false;
                var sTmpNode = "";
                int iRunId2 = 0;
                int iRunId1 = 0;
                if (obj.startDate != obj.endDate)
                {
                    uft = 2;
                }
                if (obj.updateNPO == "true")
                {
                    bUpdate = true;
                }
                else if (obj.updateNPO == "cheat")
                {
                    sTmpNode = obj.updateNPO;
                    bUpdateWithCheat = false;
                }
                if (obj.runAll)
                {
                    bAll = true;
                }
                //  Main function
                //var rsltDoc = xmlDoc.documentElement;

                //          sDate = .selectSingleNode("startDate").text
                //          eDate = .selectSingleNode("endDate").text
                //'         pos = .selectSingleNode("position").text
                // values from frontend

                var bTemp = bCheckCache(user_Number,uft, "CH", ref iRunIdCH, ref iRunbefore);
                if (iRunbefore == 1)
                {
                    if (bUpdate)
                    {
                        bTemp = bCheckCache(user_Number,uft, "FC", ref iRunIdFC, ref iRunbefore);
                        bTemp = bUpdateNPO(user_Number,ref iRunIdFC);
                    }
                    else if (bUpdateWithCheat)
                    {
                        bTemp = bUpdateNPOWithCheat(user_Number);
                    }
                    var sXML = sXMLPlyrCh(user_Number,ref iRunIdCH);
                    return sXML;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sTmpNode == "noCheat")
                    {
                        bTemp = bCheckCache(user_Number,uft, "FC", ref iRunIdFC, ref iRunbefore);
                    }
                    if (bTemp)
                    {
                        //response.write "<ffd><result>1</result><getPlayerForecast></getPlayerForecast></ffd>"
                    }
                }
                var tmpDate = obj.endDate;
                if (bAll)
                {
                    tmpDate = obj.startDate;
                }
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sql.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_scrForecast5", sql))
                        {
                            
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Number", 1953);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@runIdThisWk", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@runIdThisSeason", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            //Set objParameter = .CreateParameter("@runIdThisWk", adInteger, adParamOutput, 255);
                            //Set objParameter = .CreateParameter("@runIdThisSeason", adInteger, adParamOutput, 255);
                            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                iRunId1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@runIdThisWk"].Value);
                                iRunId2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@runIdThisSeason"].Value);
                            
                            da.Fill(table);
                            }
                        }
                        // return table;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sql.Close();
                    }
                }
                DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sql.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CacheCheatSheet", sql))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personId", 1953);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@runId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            //Set objParameter =  .CreateParameter("@runId", adInteger, adParamOutput, 255);
                            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                iRunIdCH = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@runId"].Value);
                                da.Fill(table);
                            }
                        }
                        // return table;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sql.Close();
                    }
                }
                if (bAll)
                {
                    bTemp = bCheckCache(user_Number,uft, "CH", ref iRunIdCH, ref iRunbefore);
                }
                if (bUpdate)
                {
                    bTemp = bUpdateNPO(user_Number,ref iRunId2);
                }
                else if (bUpdateWithCheat)
                {
                    bTemp = bUpdateNPOWithCheat(user_Number);
                }
                var sXMLCheat = sXMLPlyrCh(user_Number,ref iRunIdCH);
               
                return sXMLCheat ;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                List<RoboCheatDTO> Test1 = new List<RoboCheatDTO>();
                return Test1;
            }
        }
        private bool bCheckCache(int user_Number,int uft, string sAnalysisCode, ref int iRunId, ref int iRunbefore)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sql.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getSimpleRunIdV20", sql))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAnalysisCd", sAnalysisCode);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Number", user_Number);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ussForecastType", uft);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@runId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@iRunBefore", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                iRunId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@runId"].Value);
                                iRunbefore = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@iRunbefore"].Value);
                                //da.Fill(table);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sql.Close();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private bool bUpdateNPO(int user_Number,ref int iRunId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sql.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_moveFromCacheToNPO", sql))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Number", user_Number);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runId", iRunId);
                            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sql.Close();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private bool bUpdateNPOWithCheat(int user_Number)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sql.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_uftToNpo", sql))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Number", user_Number);
                            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sql.Close();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public List<RoboCheatDTO> sXMLPlyrCh(int user_Number,ref int iRunId)
        {
            List<RoboCheatDTO> roboCheat = new List<RoboCheatDTO>();
            try
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sql.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getCheatFromCache", sql))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Number", user_Number);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@runId", iRunId);
                            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                da.Fill(table);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return roboCheat;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sql.Close();
                    }
                }
                
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    roboCheat = table.ConvertToList<RoboCheatDTO>();
                    return roboCheat;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return roboCheat;
            }
            return roboCheat;
        }
    }


}


I imagine the classic ASP.NET app will be using System.Data.SqlClient and the new .NET 8 app would be using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, so they are somewhat different libraries under the covers. Have you fired up Wireshark to watch the protocol exchanges to see what's different? I'd be looking for .NET 8 attempting instance name lookups with SSRP on udp/1434.

In this  example, for simplicity, I set the db address to (local) , but in production, where I ran Profiler, both apps use the DB IP address and port.  Its not on the standard 1434 port, it looks something like 192.168.50.123,25123.  Bottom  line, I don't think there's a instance name lookup.  I'll revise the question per.

fyi, udp/1434 is the port on which the SQL Browser service listens. A default MSSQLSERVER instance would be listening on tcp/1433.

FYI "Classic ASP" refers to ASP prior to .NET written in VB or JS. I think you mean .NET Framework vs .NET Core?

Nope, I mean Classic ASP.  Also, I've configured SQL to listen on a different port.  Its a security technique as most hackers check 1433.

create a simple c# app connecting to your server using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and see if there's something fishy going on there? If not, it probably means you'll have to step through the code and see which code actually takes time

"it's a security technique". It's really not. You shouldn't have a database open to the internet. Firewalls stop people seeing your database. You're just making life hard for your self. Try changing it back to 1433 & see if it fixes the problem you're having

per @siggemannen I created a console app executable that I ran on the prod web server.   It just selected rows from a table in the prod sql db.  they were on different subnets, eg.., 192.168.50.xyz v 192.168.51.xyz.  I've got more testing to do, but this appears to be the root cause.  the executable ran much faster from computers on the 50 sql server subnet vs non-sql 51 subnet.  fyi opening the default port made no difference.

per @siggemannen I mistakenly concluded the issue was network related.  The legacy classic asp site has no latency and its on the same server as the new .net core site and so it can't be the network's fault otherwise both the legacy and the new site would have network issues.  The issue must be the configuration of or the core 8 sql library itself.

Well, did you actually do what i wrote? And tested with two different clients? Or traced the code, or anything else :)

hi @siggemannen yes, I created a new console app client.  It uses the same .net core  System.Data.SqlClient library and experiences the latency when run from a different subnet.  It works fine, no latency, on the same subnet.  Not sure how to debug this one.  Any suggestions?

Hmm, strange, but can you make sure that EF app also uses same subnet? Otherwise i guess you need to find the slow parts and then trying to step-through then in both apps to see what's different. Perhaps run a trace on the server to see if different queries are being ran for the old / new application

@siggemannen, its not the query, I think we've isolated the issue to the .net core connection library not being able to handle subnets.  the classic asp.net app handles it just fine.  same queries for both, but core can't perform across subnet.  asp classic can.  I'm going to try wireshark.

update....the root cause is Core is losing packets.  using wireshark we've found this is the case.  Classic asp loses no packets.  Not sure how to fix this....any suggestions?

extraordinary claims require extraordinary data. If the drivers used by all .NET developers since 2002 had issues, we'd know about it. Core isn't loosing packets and Classic ASP can't use ANY .NET library, only OLEDB. Even ODBC worked through an OLEDB bridge. Even if you mean ASP.NET, it's not Classic, doesn't use .NET Core libraries and doesn't lose packets

Again, as I explained above this is Classic ASP and Core 8, not ASP.Net.  And I have the evidence which I'll provide in a moment.

I know what Classic ASP is. I actually used it professionally a lot 20 years ago before going into ASP.NET. Instead of looking for evidence that hundreds of thousands of developers never encountered, post your code. If you tried migrating VBScript code directly to object-oriented code and .NET Core there will be a LOT of bad idioms, connection and memory leaks.

that isn't the case, I'll post in a moment.

uid=yyyyy;pwd=xxxxx; ??? The SQL Server keywords are User ID and Password, going back all the way to OLEDB and Classic ASP. I don't remember uid or pwd being used as synonyms

It's quite possible the freeze is caused by leaking connections. The maximum pool size is 100, which is enough for very busy web sites. Connections are meant to be short lived, and few web servers have to use 100 connections at the same time. If you don't declare connections in using blocks you risk leaving them open in case of error or accidental returns. If you store a connection in a field, you may forget to close it.

@PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the info about connections...that might be the root cause, but this site is still in test, there are only a handful of people testing it.  FYI, the issue was fixed accidentally when we added logging to the site and redeployed, we think that recycled the application pool and somehow that fixed it.

That didn't fix it, it only cleared the bottleneck. It means there is a leak though, so after a while the same problems will start again. There may be connection leaks, which means you'll hit the max pool size. Or there may be memory leaks which means the garbage collector will run, freezing the application. Although a GC run every 30s is unlikely, unless the development server has too little RAM. If this goes into production, it will start a lot sooner. If you want help, post your code.

And do listen to what Simon Halsey said. Changing the port is no security at all. Port scanners exist for over 30 years and will find the new port in less than 1 second and hacking scripts automatically do this as a smoke test for at least a decade. Firewalls not only protect against attacks based on bad packets, they can detect port scanning attempts and ban the source IPs proactively. After that, the default SSL encryption used by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient ensures the connection can't be sniffed

Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I implemented the port security thing 25 years ago. I just kept it over the years.  The SQL Server isn't open to the internet anymore...its behind the firewall.  I also am using the default port now, per Simon's suggestion.

What you just added isn't typical, although some of it was before ORMs were introduced. AddWithValues is evil in SQL Server because the parameter type and size are inferred from the value itself and can result in bad execution plans. sp_ was always reserved for system procedures. It doesn't mean stored procedure. Using it results in problems. Are you sure it's not the store procedure that causes the delay?

You're executing the stored procedure twice?? Once for .ExecuteNonQuery and once as ExecuteReader in order to load the DataTable?? Remove da completely, use ExecuteReader only once and call table.Fill(reader) at least

And please, please post your code as text. Images can't be copied, googled or compiled.

OK, never mind everything I said about packet loss.  That was a mistaken analysis.  The redeploy fixed this and we've implemented Serilog and if this happens again we'll be able to isolate the issue.

@PanagiotisKanavos I've posted the code from a typical service page per your request

The code isn't typical at all, it's full of bugs, problems and bad practices. The methods themselves can be replaced completely by single line calls like var items=await connection.Query<RoboCheatDTO>("usp_getCheatFromCache",new {user_Number,run_Id}); by using a library like Dapper or an ORM like Entity Framework. They'll be a faster too. There's no reason to load everything into a DataTable if you intend to return a list of objects. That just wastes RAM and causes increased garbage collection

thanks @PanagiotisKanavos I appreciate the best practices suggestion.  Do you think the bad practices are the root cause of the lag?

Maybe. The wasted RAM caused by DataTable along with the temporary objects generated when you add items to a list one by one certainly increase the frequency of garbage collection. When the GC runs it freezes the application and checks all objects to find which ones are orphaned and need to be cleared. The more temporary objects you create, the higher the frequency of GC runs, especially on machines with little RAM
